# RDP over VPN doesn't come from the right IP over AWS

Tags: windows-server-2008, vpn, amazon-web-services

I have the following setup:

```
local workstation -> proxy server -> Internet -> AWS -> Windows Server (VPN and RDP roles)
```

- The local proxy server has the ip: 1.2.3.4
- My AWS Windows server has the ip: 5.6.7.8
- The Windows Server is configured to give IPs through RRAS: 10.5.0.x
- The private AWS subnet in is: 172.30.0.x

Here's the issue. I can connect to 5.6.7.8 through PPTP VPN fine. If I browse the web, it shows I come from 5.6.7.8. But then if I try to RDP into 5.6.7.8, it won't work. I enabled the following inbound rules in the EC2 security group:

- All traffic from: 10.5.0.0/24
- All traffic from: 172.30.0.0/24
- All traffic from: 5.6.7.8/32

The **only** way I can make it work is if I add the following rule:

- All traffic from: 1.2.3.4/32

My question is, wtf is going on? I know I'm connected to the VPN since Google reports the right IP (5.6.7.8). Also, once connected, my RRAS server reports the connection as being from 10.5.0.15. Running `ipconfig` on the workstation shows the IP assigned to the interface is 10.5.0.15 with DNS server of 172.30.0.2 (Windows Server) and no gateway (I do NATing). Shouldn't the AWS inbound rule only need 5.6.7.8 to allow the RDP?

Also, if I try `tracert` to google.com, I see the first hop is 10.5.0.10 as expected. But if I try to traceroute to 5.6.7.8, it shows the first hop as being on the local network here.

**Edit:**
I kind of solved it, I realized I could RDP to 10.5.0.10 instead that that went through the VPN and bypassed the AWS inbound rules. I'm still curious why traffic to other ports on the server's public address isn't going through the VPN.

Comment: Are you trying to RDP to the server after you've connected to RRAS? If so, why?

Comment: The idea is to VPN in, and then RDP to the server. So RDP is disabled for anyone who isn't VPN'ed in.

Comment: If you are connecting to the windows server with PPTP, you shouldn't be trying to access it for RDP using its public IP address.  You should be using the server's private address at the other end of the tunnel... 10.5.0.1 maybe?

Comment: Good point, and I did realize that would work. However I'm still curious why connecting to its public address doesn't work. Shouldn't the traffic go through the VPN, back out on the Internet, and then back to the server's RDP port?